# Custom method implementation pattern in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I found this kind of syntax in Javascript :

```
myVariable = myClass.prototype.simpleMethod;
myClass.prototype.simpleMethod = function(params)
{
    myVariable.apply(this, arguments);
    ....
};
```

What's the purpose of this pattern?
Does the new function combine old and new implementation? Or replace it within '....'?
Can you provide a detailed explanation of this?

EDIT: Problem solved. I marked the Nas answer as accepted but the spender one could be relevant as well.

Comment: [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to wrap and "extend" the `simpleMethod`.

It could be useful if you want to define a behaviour before and/or after a method is run.

Here is line by line explanation on what each statement from your example does.

```js
// We save a reference to the current implementation of the "simpleMethod"
myVariable = myClass.prototype.simpleMethod;

// We change the "simpleMethod" implementation to have a "new implementation"
myClass.prototype.simpleMethod = function(params)
{
    // as myVariable store "the old" implementation we call the old impl. 
    // having the same this as the wrapping function.
    // passing the same args, passed to the "wrapper function"
    myVariable.apply(this, arguments);
    ....
};
```

The arguments object is a local variable available within all non-arrow functions. You can refer to a function's arguments inside that function by using its arguments object. It has entries for each argument the function was called with, with the first entry's index at 0.
(from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Answer (score 4):

It's the equivalent of an override that calls the original, base implementation. The original implementation is stored in a variable. Now the original implementation is overwritten with a new function. The first thing the new function does (with the call to `myVariable.apply(this, arguments)`) is call the original implementation with the same arguments, ensuring that `this` is preserved. See [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for more details.

[`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) is a variable that is provided by the JavaScript run-time in the context of any called function. It is an array that contains the arguments which were passed to the currently executing function (i.e. the most immediate function in the callstack). See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) for details.

Comment: Exactly. This pattern is frequently used when you either want to poly- or ponyfill a maybe existing method, or if you want to spy on the method in some way (like calling `console.log` every time it is called).

Comment: Thank you both for the explanation and the potential usecases